# Use flow router and iron router in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, flow-router

I'm using flow router for client side routing in a Meteor app. I need to use a router on the server side to expose a webhook. So, I plugged in iron router, but iron router now injects html into my app complaining I need to configure routes in the app. I guess it thinks at least one client side route should exists, er? I have implemented one iron router route in the server like so:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('webhooks', {
  layoutTemplate: null,
  path: '/webhooks/:source',
  where: 'server'
})
.post(function() {
  // auth, stuff happens, etc //
  this.response.end('Thank you, come again!');
  });
});
```

Is there some configuration I can add to iron router that tells it to calm down?

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure you can't do this, use Iron Router for JUST server side. It's pretty opinionated and nosey, and is designed to route on both sides of the street. I'll switch to https://atmospherejs.com/nimble/restivus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Picker instead

https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker/

It is designed as a dedicated server side router for meteor.

Also recommended by FlowRouter  https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/server-side-routing-rest